# Can the angle of the paddle offset a spin?

Tags: technique, table-tennis

Can the angle of the paddle offset a spin?

Say you wanted to push the ball rather than spin, can you angle the paddle in a certain way such that it will offset the spin, and able to push the ball at a high velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [allabouttabletennis.com](http://www.allabouttabletennis.com/table-tennis-techniques-spin.html) article,

> Whenever you hit the ball near its equator with your racket at a 90° angle, the ball will travel forwards more and have less, or no, spin.
>
> [image: angle]
>
> But when you brush your racket against the ball at an angle of less than 90° using an upward, downward or sideways movement, the ball will spin more and not travel as far forward.
> [image: spin]

Comment: This answer assumes that the ball had no spin on it prior to you hitting it. But the question talks about offsetting spin.

Answer (score 2):

To remove spin from the ball, you have to give it exactly the same amount of spin in the exact opposite direction.

This can be achieved by several means, such as stroke direction, speed, and of course, angle. The particular combination of those factors needed depends on the spin itself, and angle will always play a part; it may not be possible to always eliminate a need for speed however.